# How to ORDER (ROW_NUMBER() OVER PARTITION BY) BY non-selected column

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by, common-table-expression, row-number

I have a query as:

```
WITH Top_Areas AS
(
SELECT AIP.aid [Author_ID], CAST(P.research_area as VARCHAR(100)) [Research_Area], 
       P.research_area_category_id [Category],
       COUNT(*) [Paper_Count],  
       P.p_year [Paper_Year]
FROM coauthor_individual_papers AIP
JOIN sub_aminer_paper P ON AIP.pid = P.pid
WHERE AIP.aid IN (901706) AND AIP.p_year IN (2005)
GROUP BY
    AIP.aid, CAST(P.research_area as VARCHAR(100)),
    P.research_area_category_id, 
    P.p_year
),
Top_Author_Areas AS
(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Author_ID, Paper_Year ORDER BY Paper_Count DESC, Research_Area ASC) AS Rank FROM Top_Areas)

SELECT * 
FROM CTE1
WHERE Rank <= 5
```

which gives output as:

```
Author_ID   Research_Area   Category    Paper_Count Paper_Year  Rank  
--------------------------------------------------------------------
901706      feature         8           1           2005        1
901706      image annotate  11          1           2005        2
901706      image db        11          1           2005        3
901706      retrieval model 12          1           2005        4
```

This output is just ORDERING BY `Research_Area` i.e. `ASC` whereas I also need ORDERING BY `Paper_Count` i.e. `DESC`, whereas the **desired output** should be like:

```
Author_ID   Category    Paper_Count Paper_Year  Rank  
----------------------------------------------------
901706      11          2           2005        1
901706      8           1           2005        2
901706      12          1           2005        3
```

It is possible when we not to select `Research_Area` in `SELECT` list, but if we not select `Research_Area`, then how to `ORDER BY Research_Area ASC`, whereas we want to use `ORDER BY Research_Area ASC` option when `Paper_Count` value is same as shown in desired output above i.e.
`Category` 11 is at `Rank` 1 because of highest value of `Paper_Count`,
`Category` 8 and 11 are at `Rank` 2 and 3 respectively because of following reasons:

- `Paper_Count` value is same.
- So have to ORDER `Rank` 2 and 3 as by `Research_Area ASC`

How can we get desired output?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: @marc_s This is MS SQL Server database

Comment: Say we just have two categories - 1 and 2. In category 1, we have items in research area `a` and `z`. In category 2, we have items in research area `m` and `n`. What order should these be placed into?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever If number of counts for `Category` 1 is greater than `Category` 2, then surely `Category` 1 will ranked higher than `Category` 2 and vice versa. Moreover, after placing higher ranked `Category` at top, if number of `Paper_Count` is same for remaining categories, then we have to `ORDER` them by `Research_Area ASC`. Also if number of counts for `Category` are different, then there will be no problem in ranking categories as 1,2,3

Comment: But if the counts are *equal* and category 1 has areas `a` and `z` and category 2 has areas `m` and `n`, how do you *sensibly* use those values to determine the position? `a` sorts before `m`, but `z` sorts *after* `n`. You need to present us with a coherent rule to deal with this because it's currently *not* clear what to do in such a situation.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever The rule is very clear that first, we have to see the `Category`, for instance if `Category` 1 lies 3 times, `Category` 2 lies 2 times and `Category` 3 lies 1 time, then there is no need to `ORDER BY Research_Area ASC`. But if `Category` 1 lies say 3 times and other two `Categories` lies same times, then for those `Categories` we have to go to `ORDER BY Research_Area ASC` and also if all `Categories` lies same times, then `ORDER BY Research_Area ASC` clause will be straightly applied from top to bottom

Comment: But there are *different* values for `Research_Area` within the same category. So your final tie-breaking rule is currently ill-defined. Can you really not see this? I have two categories. They have the *same* `Paper_Count`. But they have a *mixture* of `Research_Area` values. Either there's some guarantee that, for instance, all `Research_Area` values for one category are *all* `<` the `Research_Area` values for another category or there's no way to make sense of this.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever You are right about having different values for `Research_Area` within same `Category`, but we have no concern with the `Research_Area` initially, and we have to target the `Categories`. Say we have a column of `Categories`, so the `Category` that exist the most in column will have top rank, similarly second most `Category` will come at number 2, third most category will come at number 3. Your point is if we have two different `Categories` in column with same `Paper_Count`, then we would go for `ORDER BY Research_Area ASC`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you still don't seem to get my point about there being possibly different `Research_Area` values when we're trying to implement *your* tie-breaking rule, I'll decide arbitrarily - we'll use the earliest `Research_Area` value within each `Category` to do the tie-breaking:

```
WITH Top_Areas AS
(
SELECT AIP.aid [Author_ID],

  MIN(CAST(P.research_area as VARCHAR(100))) [Research_Area],

       P.research_area_category_id [Category],
       COUNT(*) [Paper_Count],  
       P.p_year [Paper_Year]
FROM coauthor_individual_papers AIP
JOIN sub_aminer_paper P ON AIP.pid = P.pid
WHERE AIP.aid IN (901706) AND AIP.p_year IN (2005)
GROUP BY
    AIP.aid,

    --CAST(P.research_area as VARCHAR(100)),

    P.research_area_category_id, 
    P.p_year
),
Top_Author_Areas AS
(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Author_ID, Paper_Year
                             ORDER BY Paper_Count DESC, Research_Area ASC) AS Rank
 FROM Top_Areas)

SELECT * 
FROM CTE1
WHERE Rank <= 5
```

Changed areas are on lines separated from rest of the query by blank lines - I'm just applying `MIN` to `Research_Area` in order to obtain a *single* value for use in the tie-breaking, and have removed it from the `GROUP BY`, both changes within the `Top_Areas` CTE.